# Один тестовый метод видит файл в ClassLoader другой нет

Tags: java, junit, resources, classloader

Есть два теста:

Первый отрабатывает нормально:

```java
@Test
    void shouldReturnValidObjectFromYamlFileInClassLoader() {
        final SimplePojo expected = new SimplePojo("value", 1, new int[]{1, 2, 3});
        final SimplePojo actual = yamlTransformer.getTransformedObject(FileSource.CLASS_LOADER, "valid.yml", SimplePojo.class);

        log.info(actual.toString());

        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
```

Второй читает из того же ClassLoader, но файла уже не видит:

```java
@Test
    void shouldReturnMapFromYamlFileInClassLoader() {
        final Map<String, Object> expected = new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("string", "value");
            put("integer", 1);
            put("integerArray", new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
                add(1);
                add(2);
                add(3);
            }});
        }};

        final Map<String, Object> actual = (Map<String, Object>) yamlTransformer.getTransformedObject(FileSource.CLASS_LOADER, "valid.xml", Map.class);

        log.info(actual.toString());

        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
```

Результат второго теста:
`YamlFileNotFoundException: File valid.xml not found`

Класс валидации наличия файлов, с ним такая же проблема. Ресурса не видит:

```java
public class FileExistenceValidator {

    public void validateFileExists(FileSource source, String filename) {
        if (source == FileSource.CLASS_LOADER) {
            validateFileExistenceInClassLoader(filename);
        } else {
            validateFileExistenceInFilesystem(filename);
        }
    }

    public void validateFileExistenceInClassLoader(String filename) {
        Optional.ofNullable(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filename)).orElseThrow(() -> new YamlFileNotFoundException(String.format("File %s not found", filename)));
    }

    public void validateFileExistenceInFilesystem(String filename) {
        if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(filename))) {
            throw new YamlFileNotFoundException(String.format("File %s not found", filename));
        }
    }
}
```

Структура проекта:
[image: Структура проекта]

Comment: @RomanKonoval добавил структуру проекта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызов типа `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filename)` в зависимости от `filename` ищет ресурс в разных местах.

Если передается имя ресурса типа `valid.xml`, то оно трактуется, как относительное и ищется в том же пакете, в котором находится класс (тот который вернется `getClass`), т.е. для класса `FileExistenceValidator` из пакета `dev.demmage.simpleyamlreader` файл `valid.xml` должен лежать в `test/java/resources/dev/demmage/simpleyamlreader`.

Чтоб получить файл из корня (т.е. в существующей у вас сейчас структуре), нужно доступаться к ресурсу по полному пути в classpath, т.е. `/valid.xml`.

Тут важно понимать, что структура файлов из `test/java/resources` или `main/java/resource` попадает в корень classpath, соответственно файл из `test/java/resources` находится в корне classpath.

Comment: Спасибо! Опечатался